# Rounding issues in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

My flutter app has a rounding issue. This app consists of a quiz where a user can select True/False to answer a question. In this case, there are eleven questions and after the user answers the correct answers are divided by the total number of questions, and its percentage is found.

The circular progress indicator package seems to have no issues with this kind of fraction as shown above, but my text widget shows some weird things. I've tried rounding off, truncating and the `toStringAsFixed()` method but they all return 0. I don't know where to begin in solving this.

```
 percent = _correctScore / questionBank.length;//calculating percentage
  debugPrint(percent.round().toString()); //returns 0

              CircularPercentIndicator(
            radius: deviceInfo.width / 2.5,
            lineWidth: 8.0,
            backgroundColor: const Color(0x00000000),
            animationDuration: 2000,
            startAngle: 225,
            animation: true,
            percent: quizData.percent,
            circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
            progressColor: category.color['decoration'],
            center: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "${quizData.percent * 100}%",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 32.0,
                  ),
                ),
                const Text(
                  'YOUR SCORE',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Done, sorry forgot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually working as expected. Let's suppose the question bank has 10 questions and user gets 3 questions right:

- The correct question **ratio** is 3/10 = 0.333... If you round that, it'll be 0.
- The correct question **percentage** is 3/10 * 100 = 33.333... If you round that, it'll be 33.

You probably wanted to do something like that:

```dart
percent = 100 * _correctScore / questionBank.length; //calculating percentage
debugPrint(percent.round().toString()); // returns the correct percentage
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't realize that I had to round up after multiplying by hundred and not before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this. If the quizData.percent really returns 0.37, it will work for you.

```
Text("${(quizData.percent * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}%",
style: const TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
fontSize: 32.0,
),
)
```